# How to restore data from external hard drive before "Erase" command of Time Machine (OS X)

Tags: macos, mac, data-recovery, time-machine

I gave my external hard drive to a friend using MacBook. She plugged in and accidentally used my ext. hard drive for Time Machine.

This is what happened, according to her (I don't use Mac so I dont really know):

1. She plugged the ext. harddrive in.
2. It shows some "Time Machine" dialog. She pressed "Erase". Takes about 3 minutes.
3. Then it takes about 15 minutes to start backing up data from OSX to harddrive.

Now when I plugged the usb into my computer running windows, it shows nothing, no partition founded in Windows Explorer. Seems that all my data are lost.

Is there a way I can restore my hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She killed the partition and probably overwrote some, perhaps all of your data with a backup of her data -- depending on her aborting the process, which you didn't mention. Try using one of the popular recovery tools to get some of your data back, such as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/137351/data-recovery-from-unallocated-harddisk-partition), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/128786/need-decent-undelete-utility-for-windows), or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/117633/how-to-recover-data-from-an-external-hdd).