# Hard disk failure. Can I recover my "move"d folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am in the process of moving all my files from an old laptop to new one. I just moved 11gb of data from my old laptop to a hard drive (external) and then upon moving it out to the new hard drive, the hard drive is getting a CRC (Data Error (Cyclic Redundancy Check). Now I am looking for a solution to recover the files that I moved on my old laptop (not the external). I understand they they are just marked for potential overwriting to free up space. I was getting ready to test out GetDataBack, but it says to install it on a healthy windows and use the recover-needed drive as an external. However, I don't want to turn off my computer without first getting the okay since it is in a "moved" state. Please help! What can I do to recover the Moved files. I haven't touched the computer since it has been moved. What can I use to recover them?

Comment: Moving files off a hard disk is the same thing as deleting for the disk concerned. First they are read for copying, then deleted. Get any general purpose data recovery tool. There are lots of topics concerning these on this site.

Comment: I second @Daniel. See [Undelete utility for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/128786/need-decent-undelete-utility-for-windows) and [How to recover files from external hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/117633/how-to-recover-data-from-an-external-hdd).

Comment: @Doug When you move files onto another disk, data loss is always a risk. That's why I copy, confirm the copy, and then delete, instead of moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) - ignore the name, it recovers more than photos.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I run this on the same drive that I need to recover?

Comment: Never do that !

Comment: Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Doug Installing software, even keeping your your system running, brings the risk of writing over the "unused" disk space where your data is.

Comment: @Doug - As soon as you start using the drive you want to recover data from you run a**big** risk of having the OS overwriting data you want to recover. After all, the OS sees it as free space it can use as it pleases.

Answer (score 0):

I used Recuva (portable). It was free, and it recovered about 80%.